# Selenium finding xPath ID element that changes in Java

Tags: java, regex, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this xPath: `//*[@id="searchpopupSCH_USER_1496689382343"]`

but on the backend, the 13 digits are actually a timestamp so it changes everytime you re-test/re-click.

For example,

`1st tab, //*[@id="searchpopupSCH_USER_1496689382343"]
2nt tab, //*[@id="searchpopupSCH_USER_1496694868441"]`

Is there to target that ID that keeps changing?

I was thinking of using Reg Exp but somehow I am bit block.

```
    String frameID = "//*[@id=\"searchpopupSCH_USER_";
    String regExp = "\\d{13}";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(frameID + regExp);

    WebElement xPathUserList;
    xPathUserList.findElement(By.xpath(p));  //param of xpath only take String
```

My concern is the WebElement.

How can you target By.Path("//*[@id=\"searchpopupSCH_USER_xxxxxxxxxxxx"

thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Can't you just check if the value starts with the `searchpopupSCH_USER_`? `//*[starts-with(@id,"searchpopupSCH_USER_")]`

Comment: Why not use `parent_of_tab/tab/` ?

Comment: Yes I can, but how would you locate that WebElement?

It easy to make it By.Id("string_1234567890123";

but next time you run the test it will crash because it will not be the same digit anymore.

Comment: For sure, something in the ancestry, there's a well defined parent. Then you can go down the chain locating the tab elements.

Comment: okay well It works ok with this..
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='loadMore results']/div[1]/a[1]")).click(); `

Very unfortunate that we cannot locate it straight _by.Id_
1 commit + push from another dev... the whole script will crash again.

Answer (score 0):

use contains? or even `starts-with`

```
 //*[contains(@id, "searchpopupSCH_USER_")]
 //*[starts-with(@id, "searchpopupSCH_USER_")]
```

Comment: It might not be enough because there may be other elements that do not end with digits, and they will be returned.

Comment: you guys really use IDs not in correct way)) ok, you can make xPath dependent on some related elements, like some parent elements, etc. Some html will help much)

Comment: or you can collect all elements with ID that starts with "searchpopupSCH_USER_14" and filter only that have digits after "USER_"

Answer (score -1):

Declare a variable like below:

```
public static final String TIME_STAMP = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Then in xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xapth("//htmltag[@id="searchpopupSCH_USER_".concat(TIME_STAMP + "]"));
```

As per your requirement, you may change date format.

Comment: OP wants to handle timestamp added in Html. don't want to append self created timestamp

Comment: @D.Yan, can you share the screenshot of your DOM ?